# How to get has many association records in django

Tags: python, django

I have one events table and another table event_performance_details, each event can have more than one performances so i have to find all the performances belong to specific event, while fetching records from event table.

```
events = Event.objects.all().filter(event_start_to__gte=today, status=True, current_step=3).order_by('-id')[:3]
for event in events:
    # Here i have to get the records of event performances
```

In event_performance_details table i am using event_id as a foreign key for events table records.

EDIT: This is my template code in which i have to use nested loop for event performances

```
{% for event in events %}
    <p class="date-para">
    {% with performances = event.event_performance_details_set.all() %}
        {% for performance in performances %}
            {{ performance.city }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the problem is `{% with performances = event.event_performance_details_set.all() %}`. It should be `{% with performances = event.event_performance_details_set.all %}` instead

Comment: thanks @AndreyZarubin working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reverse relation to retrieve performances of each event like so:

```
events = Event.objects.all().filter(event_start_to__gte=today, status=True, current_step=3).order_by('-id')[:3]
for event in events:
    event.event_performance_details_set.all() # returns performances for the event
```

Edit the template like Andrey Zarubin has pointed out. Should be:

```
{% with performances = event.event_performance_details_set.all %}
    {% for performance in performances %}
        {{ performance.city }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Its working in  view but now working in django template